# Bayesian inference based on a 3$\times$3 contingency table

Tags: bayesian, contingency-tables, dirichlet-distribution, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

How do I make inferences about population parameters based on a 3$\times$3 table of observations?  In "Bernoulli's Fallacy", Aubrey Clayton provides this (Table 5.8).

|  | Democrat | Republican | Unaffiliated | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| High income | 2 | 6 | 2 | 10 |
| Middle incom | 4 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| Low income | 6 | 3 | 1 | 10 |
| Total | 12 | 10 | 3 | 25 |

Let $(h_D, m_D, l_D)$ be the proportions of high-, middle-, and low-income individuals among Democrats, and let $(h _R, m_R, l_R)$ and $(h_U, m_U, l_U)$ represent these same proportions among Republicans and unaffiliated persons, respectively. We can say the probability of observing the values given in the table is proportional to
$$h_D^2 m_D^4 l_D^6 \cdot h_R^6m_R^1l_R^3 \cdot h_U^2m_U^0l_U^1$$

**About the prior distribution:**
"...we give each triple the independent uniform prior distribution representing a state of information where all we know is that the proportions add up to 1."

**Based on the posterior distribution:**

$P(h_R > h_D) \approx 0.97$

$P(l_D > (l_R + m_R)) \approx 0.51$

$P(| h_U - h_D | < | h_U - h_R|) \approx 0.29$

How do I reproduce these calculations?  Does this mean using something like a symmetric Dirichlet prior with concentration parameter = 1?  Do I get a Dirichlet posterior distribution?  If so, how do I get the above probabilities out of it?  If this requires statistical software, I can try in R.

I appreciate any advice or a book reference for how to do calculations like this.

Comment: You may be interested in the books by David Blower. They are a thorough source on Bayesian thinking, however, very lengthy. You can download them from www.BayesInAction.nl.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe Thank you!  I downloaded the first volume from your site and have started looking through it.

Answer (score 2):

> "...we give each triple the independent uniform prior distribution
> representing a state of information where all we know is that the
> proportions add up to 1."

This implies that the author used three independent Dirichlet posterior distributions: one for each column of the table. The simplest way to evaluate the three probabilities presented is to estimate them from samples of the Dirichlet posteriors. However, using a finding from [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4019606/), we can develop a simple algorithm to calculate the first two probabilities exactly.

Implemented as an R function:

```r
betaCompare <- function(x1, x2, n1, n2, a1 = 1, a2 = 1, b1 = 1, b2 = 1) {
  # `betaCompare` calculates the probability that the difference of two random
  # variates drawn from independent Beta distributions will be greater than 0.
  # https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4019606/
  # (see formulas 2 and 3 and the "nice recursive scheme" that follows them)
  # INPUTS:
  #   xi: the number of event i events observed out of ni trials
  #   ni: the number of trials performed that resulted in xi event i events
  #   ai: the alpha parameter of the Beta distribution that provides
  #       the prior probability of event i occurring
  #   bi: the beta parameter of the Beta distribution that provides
  #       the prior probability of event i occurring
  # OUTPUT:
  #   p: the likelihood that the probability of event 1 occurrence is
  #      greater than the probability of event 2 occurrence
  
  if ((a1 - a2)%%1 || (b1 - b2)%%1) {
    stop("(a1 - a2) and (b1 - b2) must be integer")
  }
  
  A <- a1 + x1
  B <- b1 + n1 - x1
  C <- a2 + x2
  D <- b2 + n2 - x2
  
  f <- function(y1, z1, y2, z2, y3, z3, i) {
    exp(log(sum(exp(lbeta(y1, z1) - lbeta(y2, z2) - log(i)))) - lbeta(y3, z3))
  }
  
  if (B < D) {
    minBD <- B
    i <- B:(D - 1)
    p <- 0.5 + f(A + C, i + B, C, i, A, B, i)
  } else {
    minBD <- D
    
    if (B == D) {
      p <- 0.5
    } else {
      i <- D:(B - 1)
      p <- 0.5 - f(A + C, i + D, A, i, C, D, i)
    }
  }
  
  if (A < C) {
    i <- A:(C - 1)
    p <- p - f(A + i, 2*minBD, i, minBD, A, minBD, i)
  } else if (C != A) {
    i <- C:(A - 1)
    p <- p + f(C + i, 2*minBD, i, minBD, C, minBD, i)
  }
  
  p
}
```

Sample from the three posteriors to compare results from `betaCompare` to those from simulation.

```r
# define the triplet for each column of the table
nD <- c(2, 4, 6)
nR <- c(6, 1, 3)
nU <- c(2, 0, 1)

# take 1M samples from each of the Dirichlet posteriors
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_variate_generation
set.seed(1353057179)
pD <- matrix(rgamma(1e6*length(nD), rep(nD + 1, each = 1e6)), 1e6)
pR <- matrix(rgamma(1e6*length(nR), rep(nR + 1, each = 1e6)), 1e6)
pU <- matrix(rgamma(1e6*length(nU), rep(nU + 1, each = 1e6)), 1e6)
pD <- pD/rowSums(pD)
pR <- pR/rowSums(pR)
pU <- pU/rowSums(pU)
```

Now for the three probabilities of interest. (Note that [the marginal distribution of a Dirichlet random variate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_distributions) is a beta distribution.)

```r
# P(h_R > h_D)
betaCompare(6, 10, 2, 12, 1, 2, 1, 2) # exact probability
#> [1] 0.9746453
mean(pR[,1] > pD[,1]) # estimate from posterior samples
#> [1] 0.974673

# P(l_D > (l_R + m_R))
betaCompare(6, 12, 4, 10, 1, 2, 2, 1) # exact probability
#> [1] 0.511727
mean(pD[,3] > pR[,3] + pR[,2]) # estimate from posterior samples
#> [1] 0.511405
```

Finding the exact value of the third probability is not as straightforward, but obtaining a good estimate is just as simple as it was for the first two.

```r
# P(|h_U - h_D| < |h_U - h_R|)
mean(abs(pU[,1] - pD[,1]) < abs(pU[,1] - pR[,1]))
#> [1] 0.28964
```

Comment: Thank you!  You code ran perfectly.  I had already done the simulation.  Your paper about DNA methylation proportions is a specific application of a Bayesian approach to contingency tables as presented by Altham (1969).  (See my answer below.) A Bayesian approach to contingency tables must be covered in some textbook at a basic, introductory level, but I haven't found that textbook yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used a symmetric Dirichlet prior with concentration parameter 1.

Per this [reference](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1969.tb00786.x), it can be written $D(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$.

The observed counts were (2, 6, 2, 4, 1, 0, 6, 3, 1) in Clayton's Table 5.8 above, so the posterior is $D(1+2, 1+6, 1+2, 1+4, 1+0, 1+6, 1+3, 1+1)$ or  $D(3,7,3,5,2,1,7,4,2)$.

Now, the question is how to sample from this 9-parameter Dirichlet posterior.  A [previous answer](https://%20https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69212) pointed out that I can sample from independent gammas and then normalize.

Here's the R code:

```
# Function to generate Dirichlet-distributed random numbers
rdirichlet <- function(alpha) {   rgamma(length(alpha), alpha) }


# Generate N samples from Dirichlet distribution
samples <- replicate(N, rdirichlet(alphas)) 
samples <- samples / ColSums(samples) # normalize to make them Dirichlet
```

Now, I have N samples from the Dirichlet posterior distribution and can ask whatever question I like.  I was able to reproduce Clayton's calculations.

```
  [1]: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1969.tb00786.x
  [2]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69212
```