# Thompson Sampling with Two objectives - Cost and Success Rate

Tags: probability, reinforcement-learning, beta-distribution, multiarmed-bandit, thompson-sampling

I have implemented a Thompson sampling algorithm with beta distribution that chooses between two processors to process the payments for each transaction such that it maximizes the success rate. For each transaction, there are only two available processors and for different transactions, these two processors can vary.

1. Now for a merchant, I see that processor1 has been always performing better than processor2, but still processor2 is receiving a good amount of traffic, I believe processor 2 is receiving traffic because of the inherent nature of Thompson sampling where it wants to `explore`. How do I control this exploration and if I have sufficient confidence, it should exploit processor1.
2. Now these processors can have different prices. I want to extend the algorithm such that it selects the processor that is cheap and within a certain threshold of Success Rate. How can I do that? Can I include pricing as a parameter in beta distribution?

Comment: What is the cost of unsuccessfully processing a transaction?

Comment: for successful, we can assume the reward as 1, and for unsuccessful, we can assume the reward as 0

Comment: Yes, but "these processors can have different prices". I take it the price is the same regardless of success?

Comment: So, to process a payment through processor1, the price (expense to use that processor) could be p1, for processor2, the price(or expense) could be p2.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, Thompson sampling automatically balances exploration vs exploitation.

To illustrate, consider the case where the actual (unknown) probabilities of success are $\theta_1=0.9$ and $\theta_2=0.7$. Using a uniform prior for $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, we can simulate the sampling process and track the probability of choosing process 2.

The plot below shows 100 replications of simulating 1,000 trials. The red line is the median. After 1,000 trials, Thompson sampling would choose process 2 over 1 typically with a probability less than 0.0012, which could be interpreted as the sampling process being dominated by exploitation due to the strength of the evidence favoring process 1.

[image]

For the second question, in Thompson sampling the action chosen in each round is the one that maximizes the expected reward after sampling the parameters from their respective posterior distributions. Here, the expected reward for choosing process $i$ is $r_i\theta^*_i - p_i$, where $\theta^*_i$ is a probability of success of process $i$ sampled from its posterior distribution, $r_i$ is the payout for a successful process, and $p_i$ is the processing cost. For example, if you have observed $k_1$ successes out of $n_1$ times of choosing process 1 and $k_2$ successes out of $n_2$ times of choosing process 2, first sample the posterior probabilities of success ($\theta^*_1$ and $\theta^*_2$) from:

$$\text{Beta}(\alpha_1+k_1,\beta_1+n_1-k_1)$$
$$\text{Beta}(\alpha_2+k_2,\beta_2+n_2-k_2)$$

(where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are the parameters from the Beta prior of $\theta_i$). We choose process 1 if $r_1\theta^*_1-p_1>r_2\theta^*_2-p_2$ and process 2 otherwise.

---

### R code

```
N <- 100 # replications
n <- 1e3 # simulation length
# initialize the beta parameter array: (alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2) in the
# third dimension
ab <- array(1L, c(N, n + 1, 4))
theta <- c(0.9, 0.7) # probabilities of success
m0 <- m1 <- matrix(1:N, N, 3) # indexing matrices
p1LT2 <- matrix(0, N, n) # initialize the probability matrix to output
f <- function(x) betaCompare(x[2], x[1], x[2] + x[4], x[1] + x[3])

for (i in 1:n) {
  m0[,2] <- i
  m1[,2] <- i + 1L
  # which process to try
  j <- (rbeta(N, ab[,i, 1], ab[,i, 3]) < rbeta(N, ab[,i, 2], ab[,i, 4])) + 1L
  # which parameter to update
  m0[,3] <- m1[,3] <- 2L*(runif(N) > theta[j]) + j
  ab[,i + 1,] <- ab[,i,]
  ab[m1] <- ab[m0] + 1L
  # update the posterior probability that theta1 < theta2
  x <- asplit(ab[,i + 1,] - 1L, 1)
  u <- unique(c(x))
  p1LT2[,i] <- sapply(u, f)[match(x, u)]
}

# prior probability that theta1 < theta2
p1LT2 <- cbind(0.5, p1LT2)
# plot individual traces
matplot(0:n, t(p1LT2), type = "l", lty = 1, col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1))
# plot median
lines(0:n, Rfast::colMedians(p1LT2), col = "red")
```

Comment: Would be the r code made available? thx.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the R code, so I recreated it, but I don't have the random seed for the original plot. I used [this function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/620803/214015) to calculate the posterior probabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much!