Sample from a population such that it follows a given Dirichlet distribution
I have a store of probability scores (~ around 2 million scores) in the following format - [[0.1,0.2,0.7],[0.4,0.15,0.45], ...]
I want to sample from these scores such that their empirical distribution to close to a Dirichlet distribution, say, D(1,2,3).
Any pointers on how to proceed?

Try this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69210/drawing-from-dirichlet-distribution
